# How does this function print strings in the reverse order?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, reverse, c-strings

I am learning about strings and characters in c programming.Today i saw a code that print strings in the reverse order but i don't understand how it works.Can you help me to understand it ?

```
  void reverse(const char * const sPtr)
    {

    if ('\0' == sPtr[0]) {
         return;
    }

    else { 
          reverse(&sPtr[1]); 
          putchar(sPtr[0]);
          }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't.   It simply prints the characters of the string in reverse order.

Comment: [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Answer (score 9):

> I don't understand that how does this function reverse the strings

The function does not reverse a string. Its parameter is declared with the qualifier `const`.

```
void reverse(const char * const sPtr);
             ^^^^^
```

It outputs a string in the reverse order.

Due to these statements

```
  reverse(&sPtr[1]); 
  putchar(sPtr[0]);
```

the first character of the string is outputted last and the last character before the terminating zero is outputted first.

The function can be written simpler as for example

```
void reverse( const char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        reverse( s + 1 ); 
        putchar( *s );
    }
}
```

Let's assume that `s` is a pointer to the first character of string literal `"Hello"`.

Then as the character 'H' is not equal to 0 ( `if ( *s )` ) then the function call itself passing a pointer to to the second character that is to `'e'`.

Again 'e' is not equal to 0 so the function call itself recursively. It will call itself until the expression in the if statement `if ( *s )` is evaluate to false that is then `*s` is equal to `'\0'`. So the previous calls of the function outputs their corresponding characters

```
putchar( *s );
```

You can imagine this the following way

```
1 reverse( "Hello"[0] ); 
2 reverse( "ello"[0] ); 
3 reverse( "llo"[0] ); 
4 reverse( "lo"[0] ); 
5 reverse( "o"[0] ); 
6 reverse( ""[0] ); 
6 // do not call putchar 
5 putchar( 'o' );
4 putchar( 'l' );
3 putchar( 'l' );
2 putchar( 'e' );
1 putchar( 'H' );
```

Comment: Thank you i mean how to print strings in reverse order but i wrote reverse strings i'll correct it.

Answer (score 3):

The function *outputs* the string in reverse. It's a recursive function, this statement calls the function itself.

```
 reverse(&sPtr[1]);
```

Take a string "abc" as an example:

`reverse("abc");` 
sPtr is not null, so `reverse(&sPtr[1]);` is called with parameter `&sPtr[1]` pointing to "bc". And so on.

```
reverse("abc");
reverse("bc");
reverse("c");    
reverse("");  //Now sPtr is null, reverse() returns to `reverse("c") frame:

// just returned from reverse("c") call so do 
// next statement following it 
// in reverse("bc") frame.
putchar(sPtr[0]); //  outputs "c" 

// reverse("c") frame reaches function end 
// so returns back from reverse("bc")
// call and executes next statement 
// after reverse("bc") 
putchar(sPtr[0]); //  outputs "b" 

// reverse("bc") frame reaches function end 
// so returns back from reverse("abc")
// call and executes next statement 
// after reverse("abc") 
putchar(sPtr[0]); //  outputs "a"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am still  confused about this code.Could you explain more in detail how return statement and putchar()  works in this function ? Recursive step comes hard to me if there is return.

Comment: I've tried - it may help you to run through the logic of the program with a debugger. Recursion can be confusing at first.